# Как исправить некорректное отображение css3 анимации (особенно в Firefox)?

Tags: css, css3, css-animation

Возникла проблема с css3 анимацией.
В Chrome появляется черная или белая полоса посередине у нескольких блоков.
В Firefox все намного хуже: вместо 3d поворота, фото перекручивается, некоторые фото резко отражаются.

Результат (для уменьшения кода сниппета изменено изображение):

```css
* {
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

.photo-cube {
 background-color: #000;
 display: inline-block;
 width: 280px;
 margin: 0;
 float: left;
 font-size: 0;
}

.stage img {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

.stage {
 vertical-align: top;
 overflow: hidden;
 display: inline-block;
 border: 1px solid #363636;
}

.stage1 {
 width: 93.3px;
 height: 80px;
}

.stage2 {
 width: 93.4px;
 height: 80px;
}

.stage3 {
 width: 93.3px;
 height: 145px;
 float: right;
}

.stage4 {
 width: 62px;
 height: 65px;
}

.stage5 {
 width: 62px;
 height: 65px;
}

.stage6 {
 width: 62.7px;
 height: 65px;
}

.stage7 {
 width: 140px;
 height: 140px;
 float: left;
}

.stage8 {
 width: 140px;
 height: 70px;
}

.stage9 {
 width: 140px;
 height: 70px;
}

.cubespinner {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 -webkit-animation-name: spincube;
 animation-name: spincube;
 -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
 animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
 -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
 animation-iteration-count: infinite;
 -webkit-animation-duration: 15s;
 animation-duration: 15s;
 -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
 transform-style: preserve-3d;
 -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0 0;
 -ms-transform-origin: 50% 0 0;
 transform-origin: 50% 0 0;
}

.cubespinner div {
 position: absolute;
 width: 94px;
 height: 80px;
 background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .6);
 text-align: center;
 color: #55bede;
}

.cubespinner .face1 {
 -webkit-transform: translateZ(47px);
 transform: translateZ(47px);
}

.cubespinner .face2 {
 -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(47px);
 transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(47px);
}

.cubespinner .face3 {
 -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg) rotateX(90deg) translateZ(47px);
 transform: rotateY(0deg) rotateX(90deg) translateZ(47px);
}

.cubespinner .face4 {
 -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg) rotateZ(0deg) translateZ(46px);
 transform: rotateY(180deg) rotateZ(0deg) translateZ(46px);
}

.cubespinner .face5 {
 -webkit-transform: rotateY(-90deg) rotateZ(0deg) translateZ(47px);
 transform: rotateY(-90deg) rotateZ(0deg) translateZ(47px);
}

.cubespinner .face6 {
 -webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(47px);
 transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(47px);
}

@-webkit-keyframes spincube {
 from,
 to {}
 10%,
 25% {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-90deg);
 }
 35%,
 50% {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
 }
 60%,
 75% {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-270deg);
 }
 85%,
 100% {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-360deg);
 }
}

@keyframes spincube {
 from,
 to {}
 10%,
 25% {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-90deg);
 }
 35%,
 50% {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
 }
 60%,
 75% {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-270deg);
 }
 85%,
 100% {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-360deg);
 }
}

.cubespinner2 {
 -webkit-animation-name: spincube2;
 animation-name: spincube2;
 -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
 animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
 -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
 animation-iteration-count: infinite;
 -webkit-animation-duration: 8s;
 animation-duration: 8s;
 -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
 transform-style: preserve-3d;
 -webkit-transform-origin: 0 40px 0;
 -ms-transform-origin: 0 40px 0;
 transform-origin: 0 40px 0;
}

.cubespinner2 div {
 position: absolute;
 width: 100px;
 height: 80px;
 background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .6);
 text-align: center;
 color: #55bede;
}

.cubespinner2 .face1 {
 -webkit-transform: translateZ(40px);
 transform: translateZ(40px);
}

.cubespinner2 .face2 {
 -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(40px);
 transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(40px);
}

.cubespinner2 .face3 {
 -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg) rotateX(90deg) translateZ(40px);
 transform: rotateY(0deg) rotateX(90deg) translateZ(40px);
}

.cubespinner2 .face4 {
 -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg) rotateZ(180deg) translateZ(40px);
 transform: rotateY(180deg) rotateZ(180deg) translateZ(40px);
}

.cubespinner2 .face5 {
 -webkit-transform: rotateY(-90deg) rotateZ(0deg) translateZ(40px);
 transform: rotateY(-90deg) rotateZ(0deg) translateZ(40px);
}

.cubespinner2 .face6 {
 -webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(40px);
 transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(40px);
}

@-webkit-keyframes spincube2 {
 from,
 to {}
 10%,
 25% {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg);
 }
 35%,
 50% {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(-180deg);
 }
 60%,
 75% {
  -webkit-transform: rotatX(-270deg);
 }
 85%,
 100% {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(-360deg);
 }
}

@keyframes spincube2 {
 from,
 to {}
 10%,
 25% {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg);
 }
 35%,
 50% {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(-180deg);
 }
 60%,
 75% {
  -webkit-transform: rotatX(-270deg);
 }
 85%,
 100% {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(-360deg);
 }
}

.cubespinner3 {
 -webkit-animation-name: spincube;
 animation-name: spincube;
 -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
 animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
 -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
 animation-iteration-count: infinite;
 -webkit-animation-duration: 13s;
 animation-duration: 13s;
 -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
 transform-style: preserve-3d;
 -webkit-transform-origin: 47px 0 0;
 -ms-transform-origin: 47px 0 0;
 transform-origin: 47px 0 0;
}

.cubespinner3 div {
 position: absolute;
 width: 94px;
 height: 160px;
 background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .6);
 text-align: center;
 color: #55bede;
}

.cubespinner3 .face1 {
 -webkit-transform: translateZ(47px);
 transform: translateZ(47px);
}

.cubespinner3 .face2 {
 -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(47px);
 transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(47px);
}

.cubespinner3 .face3 {
 -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg) rotateX(90deg) translateZ(47px);
 transform: rotateY(0deg) rotateX(90deg) translateZ(47px);
}

.cubespinner3 .face4 {
 -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg) rotateZ(0deg) translateZ(47px);
 transform: rotateY(180deg) rotateZ(0deg) translateZ(47px);
}

.cubespinner3 .face5 {
 -webkit-transform: rotateY(-90deg) rotateZ(0deg) translateZ(47px);
 transform: rotateY(-90deg) rotateZ(0deg) translateZ(47px);
}

.cubespinner3 .face6 {
 -webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(47px);
 transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(47px);
}

@-webkit-keyframes spincube3 {
 from,
 to {}
 10%,
 25% {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg);
 }
 35%,
 50% {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);
 }
 60%,
 75% {
  -webkit-transform: rotatX(270deg);
 }
 85%,
 100% {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(360deg);
 }
}

@keyframes spincube3 {
 from,
 to {}
 10%,
 25% {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg);
 }
 35%,
 50% {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);
 }
 60%,
 75% {
  -webkit-transform: rotatX(270deg);
 }
 85%,
 100% {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(360deg);
 }
}

.cubespinner4 {
 -webkit-animation-name: spincube4;
 animation-name: spincube4;
 -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
 animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
 -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
 animation-iteration-count: infinite;
 -webkit-animation-duration: 15s;
 animation-duration: 15s;
 -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
 transform-style: preserve-3d;
 -webkit-transform-origin: 0 40px 0;
 -ms-transform-origin: 0 40px 0;
 transform-origin: 0 40px 0;
}

.cubespinner4 div {
 position: absolute;
 width: 62px;
 height: 80px;
 background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .6);
 text-align: center;
 color: #55bede;
}

.cubespinner4 .face1 {
 -webkit-transform: translateZ(40px);
 transform: translateZ(40px);
}

.cubespinner4 .face2 {
 -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(40px);
 transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(40px);
}

.cubespinner4 .face3 {
 -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg) rotateX(90deg) translateZ(40px);
 transform: rotateY(0deg) rotateX(90deg) translateZ(40px);
}

.cubespinner4 .face4 {
 -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg) rotateZ(180deg) translateZ(40px);
 transform: rotateY(180deg) rotateZ(180deg) translateZ(40px);
}

.cubespinner4 .face5 {
 -webkit-transform: rotateY(-90deg) rotateZ(0deg) translateZ(40px);
 transform: rotateY(-90deg) rotateZ(0deg) translateZ(40px);
}

.cubespinner4 .face6 {
 -webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(40px);
 transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(40px);
}

@-webkit-keyframes spincube4 {
 from,
 to {}
 10%,
 25% {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg);
 }
 35%,
 50% {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);
 }
 60%,
 75% {
  -webkit-transform: rotatX(270deg);
 }
 85%,
 100% {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(360deg);
 }
}

@keyframes spincube4 {
 from,
 to {}
 10%,
 25% {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg);
 }
 35%,
 50% {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);
 }
 60%,
 75% {
  -webkit-transform: rotatX(270deg);
 }
 85%,
 100% {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(360deg);
 }
}

.cubespinner5 {
 -webkit-animation-name: spincube5;
 animation-name: spincube5;
 -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
 animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
 -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
 animation-iteration-count: infinite;
 -webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
 animation-duration: 5s;
 -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
 transform-style: preserve-3d;
 -webkit-transform-origin: 31px 0 0;
 -ms-transform-origin: 31px 0 0;
 transform-origin: 31px 0 0;
}

.cubespinner5 div {
 position: absolute;
 width: 62px;
 height: 80px;
 background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .6);
 text-align: center;
 color: #55bede;
}

.cubespinner5 .face1 {
 -webkit-transform: translateZ(31px);
 transform: translateZ(31px);
}

.cubespinner5 .face2 {
 -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(31px);
 transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(31px);
}

.cubespinner5 .face3 {
 -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg) rotateX(90deg) translateZ(31px);
 transform: rotateY(0deg) rotateX(90deg) translateZ(31px);
}

.cubespinner5 .face4 {
 -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg) rotateZ(0deg) translateZ(31px);
 transform: rotateY(180deg) rotateZ(0deg) translateZ(31px);
}

.cubespinner5 .face5 {
 -webkit-transform: rotateY(-90deg) rotateZ(0deg) translateZ(31px);
 transform: rotateY(-90deg) rotateZ(0deg) translateZ(31px);
}

.cubespinner5 .face6 {
 -webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(31px);
 transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(31px);
}

@-webkit-keyframes spincube5 {
 from,
 to {}
 10%,
 25% {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);
 }
 35%,
 50% {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
 }
 60%,
 75% {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(270deg);
 }
 85%,
 100% {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(360deg);
 }
}

@keyframes spincube5 {
 from,
 to {}
 10%,
 25% {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);
 }
 35%,
 50% {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
 }
 60%,
 75% {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(270deg);
 }
 85%,
 100% {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(360deg);
 }
}

.cubespinner6 {
 -webkit-animation-name: spincube6;
 animation-name: spincube6;
 -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
 animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
 -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
 animation-iteration-count: infinite;
 -webkit-animation-duration: 11s;
 animation-duration: 11s;
 -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
 transform-style: preserve-3d;
 -webkit-transform-origin: 31px 0 0;
 -ms-transform-origin: 31px 0 0;
 transform-origin: 31px 0 0;
}

.cubespinner6 div {
 position: absolute;
 width: 64px;
 height: 80px;
 background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .6);
 text-align: center;
 /*font-size: 100px;*/
 color: #55bede;
}

.cubespinner6 .face1 {
 -webkit-transform: translateZ(32px);
 transform: translateZ(32px);
}

.cubespinner6 .face2 {
 -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(31px);
 transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(31px);
}

.cubespinner6 .face3 {
 -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg) rotateX(90deg) translateZ(31px);
 transform: rotateY(0deg) rotateX(90deg) translateZ(31px);
}

.cubespinner6 .face4 {
 -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg) rotateZ(0deg) translateZ(31px);
 transform: rotateY(180deg) rotateZ(0deg) translateZ(31px);
}

.cubespinner6 .face5 {
 -webkit-transform: rotateY(-90deg) rotateZ(0deg) translateZ(31px);
 transform: rotateY(-90deg) rotateZ(0deg) translateZ(31px);
}

.cubespinner6 .face6 {
 -webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(31px);
 transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(31px);
}

@-webkit-keyframes spincube6 {
 from,
 to {}
 10%,
 25% {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-90deg);
 }
 35%,
 50% {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
 }
 60%,
 75% {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-270deg);
 }
 85%,
 100% {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-360deg);
 }
}

@keyframes spincube6 {
 from,
 to {}
 10%,
 25% {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-90deg);
 }
 35%,
 50% {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
 }
 60%,
 75% {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-270deg);
 }
 85%,
 100% {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-360deg);
 }
}

.cubespinner8 {
 -webkit-animation-name: spincube8;
 animation-name: spincube8;
 -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
 animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
 -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
 animation-iteration-count: infinite;
 -webkit-animation-duration: 9s;
 animation-duration: 9s;
 -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
 transform-style: preserve-3d;
 -webkit-transform-origin: 0 35px 0;
 -ms-transform-origin: 0 35px 0;
 transform-origin: 0 35px 0;
}

.cubespinner8 div {
 position: absolute;
 width: 140px;
 height: 70px;
 background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .6);
 text-align: center;
 /*font-size: 100px;*/
 color: #55bede;
}

.cubespinner8 .face1 {
 -webkit-transform: translateZ(35px);
 transform: translateZ(35px);
}

.cubespinner8 .face2 {
 -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(35px);
 transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(35px);
}

.cubespinner8 .face3 {
 -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg) rotateX(90deg) translateZ(35px);
 transform: rotateY(0deg) rotateX(90deg) translateZ(35px);
}

.cubespinner8 .face4 {
 -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg) rotateZ(180deg) translateZ(35px);
 transform: rotateY(180deg) rotateZ(180deg) translateZ(35px);
}

.cubespinner8 .face5 {
 -webkit-transform: rotateY(-90deg) rotateZ(0deg) translateZ(35px);
 transform: rotateY(-90deg) rotateZ(0deg) translateZ(35px);
}

.cubespinner8 .face6 {
 -webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(35px);
 transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(35px);
}

@-webkit-keyframes spincube8 {
 from,
 to {}
 10%,
 25% {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg);
 }
 35%,
 50% {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);
 }
 60%,
 75% {
  -webkit-transform: rotatX(270deg);
 }
 85%,
 100% {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(360deg);
 }
}

@keyframes spincube8 {
 from,
 to {}
 10%,
 25% {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg);
 }
 35%,
 50% {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);
 }
 60%,
 75% {
  -webkit-transform: rotatX(270deg);
 }
 85%,
 100% {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(360deg);
 }
}

.cubespinner7 {
 -webkit-animation-name: spincube7;
 animation-name: spincube7;
 -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
 animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
 -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
 animation-iteration-count: infinite;
 -webkit-animation-duration: 7s;
 animation-duration: 7s;
 -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
 transform-style: preserve-3d;
 -webkit-transform-origin: 70px 0 0;
 -ms-transform-origin: 70px 0 0;
 transform-origin: 70px 0 0;
}

.cubespinner7 div {
 position: absolute;
 width: 140px;
 height: 140px;
 background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .6);
 text-align: center;
 /*font-size: 100px;*/
 color: #55bede;
}

.cubespinner7 .face1 {
 -webkit-transform: translateZ(70px);
 transform: translateZ(70px);
}

.cubespinner7 .face2 {
 -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(70px);
 transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(70px);
}

.cubespinner7 .face3 {
 -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg) rotateX(90deg) translateZ(70px);
 transform: rotateY(0deg) rotateX(90deg) translateZ(70px);
}

.cubespinner7 .face4 {
 -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg) rotateZ(0deg) translateZ(70px);
 transform: rotateY(180deg) rotateZ(0deg) translateZ(70px);
}

.cubespinner7 .face5 {
 -webkit-transform: rotateY(-90deg) rotateZ(0deg) translateZ(70px);
 transform: rotateY(-90deg) rotateZ(0deg) translateZ(70px);
}

.cubespinner7 .face6 {
 -webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(70px);
 transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(70px);
}

@-webkit-keyframes spincube7 {
 from,
 to {}
 10%,
 25% {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-90deg);
 }
 35%,
 50% {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
 }
 60%,
 75% {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-270deg);
 }
 85%,
 100% {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-360deg);
 }
}

@keyframes spincube7 {
 from,
 to {}
 10%,
 25% {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-90deg);
 }
 35%,
 50% {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
 }
 60%,
 75% {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-270deg);
 }
 85%,
 100% {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-360deg);
 }
}

.cubespinner9 {
 -webkit-animation-name: spincube9;
 animation-name: spincube9;
 -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
 animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
 -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
 animation-iteration-count: infinite;
 -webkit-animation-duration: 11s;
 animation-duration: 11s;
 -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
 transform-style: preserve-3d;
 -webkit-transform-origin: 70px 0 0;
 -ms-transform-origin: 70px 0 0;
 transform-origin: 70px 0 0;
}

.cubespinner9 div {
 position: absolute;
 width: 140px;
 height: 70px;
 background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .6);
 text-align: center;
 /*font-size: 100px;*/
 color: #55bede;
}

.cubespinner9 .face1 {
 -webkit-transform: translateZ(70px);
 transform: translateZ(70px);
}

.cubespinner9 .face2 {
 -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(70px);
 transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(70px);
}

.cubespinner9 .face3 {
 -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg) rotateX(90deg) translateZ(70px);
 transform: rotateY(0deg) rotateX(90deg) translateZ(70px);
}

.cubespinner9 .face4 {
 -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg) rotateZ(0deg) translateZ(70px);
 transform: rotateY(180deg) rotateZ(0deg) translateZ(70px);
}

.cubespinner9 .face5 {
 -webkit-transform: rotateY(-90deg) rotateZ(0deg) translateZ(70px);
 transform: rotateY(-90deg) rotateZ(0deg) translateZ(70px);
}

.cubespinner9 .face6 {
 -webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(70px);
 transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(70px);
}

@-webkit-keyframes spincube9 {
 from,
 to {}
 10%,
 25% {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);
 }
 35%,
 50% {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
 }
 60%,
 75% {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(270deg);
 }
 85%,
 100% {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(360deg);
 }
}
@keyframes spincube9 {
 from,
 to {}
 10%,
 25% {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);
 }
 35%,
 50% {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
 }
 60%,
 75% {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(270deg);
 }
 85%,
 100% {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(360deg);
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="photo-cube">
 <div class="stage stage1">
  <div class="cubespinner">
   <div class="face1"><img src="https://placeimg.com/245/265/people"></div>
   <div class="face2"><img src="https://placeimg.com/245/265/people"></div>
   <div class="face3"><img src="https://placeimg.com/245/265/people"></div>
   <div class="face4"><img src="https://placeimg.com/245/265/people"></div>
   <div class="face5"><img src="https://placeimg.com/245/265/people"></div>
   <div class="face6"><img src="https://placeimg.com/245/265/people"></div>
   <div class="face7"><img src="https://placeimg.com/245/265/people"></div>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div class="stage stage2">
  <div class="cubespinner2">
   <div class="face1"><img src="https://placeimg.com/245/265/people"></div>
   <div class="face2"><img src="https://placeimg.com/245/265/people"></div>
   <div class="face3"><img src="https://placeimg.com/245/265/people"></div>
   <div class="face4"><img src="https://placeimg.com/245/265/people"></div>
   <div class="face5"><img src="https://placeimg.com/245/265/people"></div>
   <div class="face6"><img src="https://placeimg.com/245/265/people"></div>
   <div class="face7"><img src="https://placeimg.com/245/265/people"></div>
  </div>

 </div>

 <div class="stage stage3">
  <div class="cubespinner3">
   <div class="face1"><img src="https://placeimg.com/245/265/people"></div>
   <div class="face2"><img src="https://placeimg.com/245/265/people"></div>
   <div class="face3"><img src="https://placeimg.com/245/265/people"></div>
   <div class="face4"><img src="https://placeimg.com/245/265/people"></div>
   <div class="face5"><img src="https://placeimg.com/245/265/people"></div>
   <div class="face6"><img src="https://placeimg.com/245/265/people"></div>
   <div class="face7"><img src="https://placeimg.com/245/265/people"></div>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div class="stage stage4">
  <div class="cubespinner4">
   <div class="face1"><img src="https://placeimg.com/245/265/people"></div>
   <div class="face2"><img src="https://placeimg.com/245/265/people"></div>
   <div class="face3"><img src="https://placeimg.com/245/265/people"></div>
   <div class="face4"><img src="https://placeimg.com/245/265/people"></div>
   <div class="face5"><img src="https://placeimg.com/245/265/people"></div>
   <div class="face6"><img src="https://placeimg.com/245/265/people"></div>
   <div class="face7"><img src="https://placeimg.com/245/265/people"></div>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div class="stage stage5">
  <div class="cubespinner5">
   <div class="face1"><img src="https://placeimg.com/245/265/people"></div>
   <div class="face2"><img src="https://placeimg.com/245/265/people"></div>
   <div class="face3"><img src="https://placeimg.com/245/265/people"></div>
   <div class="face4"><img src="https://placeimg.com/245/265/people"></div>
   <div class="face5"><img src="https://placeimg.com/245/265/people"></div>
   <div class="face6"><img src="https://placeimg.com/245/265/people"></div>
   <div class="face7"><img src="https://placeimg.com/245/265/people"></div>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div class="stage stage6">
  <div class="cubespinner6">
   <div class="face1"><img src="https://placeimg.com/245/265/people"></div>
   <div class="face2"><img src="https://placeimg.com/245/265/people"></div>
   <div class="face3"><img src="https://placeimg.com/245/265/people"></div>
   <div class="face4"><img src="https://placeimg.com/245/265/people"></div>
   <div class="face5"><img src="https://placeimg.com/245/265/people"></div>
   <div class="face6"><img src="https://placeimg.com/245/265/people"></div>
   <div class="face7"><img src="https://placeimg.com/245/265/people"></div>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div class="stage stage7">
  <div class="cubespinner7">
   <div class="face1"><img src="https://placeimg.com/245/265/people"></div>
   <div class="face2"><img src="https://placeimg.com/245/265/people"></div>
   <div class="face3"><img src="https://placeimg.com/245/265/people"></div>
   <div class="face4"><img src="https://placeimg.com/245/265/people"></div>
   <div class="face5"><img src="https://placeimg.com/245/265/people"></div>
   <div class="face6"><img src="https://placeimg.com/245/265/people"></div>
   <div class="face7"><img src="https://placeimg.com/245/265/people"></div>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div class="stage stage8">
  <div class="cubespinner8">
   <div class="face1"><img src="https://placeimg.com/245/265/people"></div>
   <div class="face2"><img src="https://placeimg.com/245/265/people"></div>
   <div class="face3"><img src="https://placeimg.com/245/265/people"></div>
   <div class="face4"><img src="https://placeimg.com/245/265/people"></div>
   <div class="face5"><img src="https://placeimg.com/245/265/people"></div>
   <div class="face6"><img src="https://placeimg.com/245/265/people"></div>
   <div class="face7"><img src="https://placeimg.com/245/265/people"></div>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div class="stage stage9">
  <div class="cubespinner9">
   <div class="face1"><img src="https://placeimg.com/245/265/people"></div>
   <div class="face2"><img src="https://placeimg.com/245/265/people"></div>
   <div class="face3"><img src="https://placeimg.com/245/265/people"></div>
   <div class="face4"><img src="https://placeimg.com/245/265/people"></div>
   <div class="face5"><img src="https://placeimg.com/245/265/people"></div>
   <div class="face6"><img src="https://placeimg.com/245/265/people"></div>
   <div class="face7"><img src="https://placeimg.com/245/265/people"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Оригинал: https://codepen.io/dan_postnov/pen/gxBJBL